# SQL Query to get data based on multiple filters

Tags: sql-server

I have following **Product** table and **ProductTag** tables -

```
ID  | Product
-------------- 
1   | Product_A
2   | Product_B
3   | Product_C

TagID   |   ProductID
----------------------
1       |      2
1       |      3
2       |      1
2       |      2
2       |      3
3       |      1
3       |      2
```

Now I need a SQL query that return all products list which are having both Tag 1 and 2. Result should be as given below -

```
ProductID   |    Product   
------------------------
2           |      Product_B
3           |     Product_C
```

Please suggest how can i write a MS SQL query for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  p.ID, p.Product
FROM    Product p
        INNER JOIN ProductTag pt
            ON p.ID = pt.ProductID
WHERE   pt.TagID IN (1, 2)           -- <== Tags you want to find
GROUP   BY p.ID, o.Product
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2                 -- <== tag count on WHERE clause
```

however, if `TagID` is not unique on every `Product`, you need to count only the distinct product.

```
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT pt.TagID) = 2
```

- [More on: SQL of Relational Division](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)